# What does “Blarek” mean?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, wax-wayne-novels

In chapter 9 of *The Alloy of Law*, Wayne apparently curses with the word “Blarek.” Is this fictional slang, or is it some random mythological figure or something (like how “Ruin” is a curse) on Scadrial?

Comment: Unless someone has a more definite answer, I'm inclined to interpret "blarek" as more of a disgust sound, like yuck or blah. Just kind of a weird noise to express distaste. Though it's a pretty weird one if that's what Sanderson was going for.

Comment: Anothet reason I don't think it's a standard curse on Scadrial is that it's the only instance of blarek in the book. Sanderson is a pretty good world builder. It wouldn't be like him to drop that and never pick it up a again. He uses the other curses enough that you come to understand what a character is expressing when they say "ruin".

Comment: I suspect it's just a "Wayne-ish" onomatopoeic expletive more than anything else